# Avoid creating white margins in tile cache in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I'm relatively new in Geographic Information Systems and in ArcGIS software in general so I have no idea how to handle the following situation. I'm using a ArcMap software to create and publish a map service, which should be used as a tile cache for our software. I've created a tile scheme that suits our organization the best, set the correct projection, and level of details. The problem I'm having is that once the service is published and cache is created, there are white margins on tiles on the edges. This is a problem since we use this tiles in our software and the image is shown shifted to the side by those margins. The map is pretty simple, it's just one georeferenced image, nothing special for now. Is there any way to remove these margins from tile images?

[image]

Comment: Please add the screenshot of the created map and desired map for better understanding.

Comment: I've found the answer but here is the image just in case anybody else came up with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: The problem (well not exactly a problem, it was more of me not understanding how ArcMap works) was solved by setting the origin of the tile scheme at the upper left corner of my map, and setting the resolution on all my level of details to cover the exact area of the images. So basically this was done: resolution = whole_image_area_width / (image_size * number_of_tiles), meaning that this resolution should be used if you want to cover a whole area width with the wanted number of tiles with specified size, considering that tile creation starts in the upper left corner of the image.